# How to get Facebook account linking event in Dialogflow intent?

Tags: facebook, dialogflow-es, chatbot, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-chatbot

I am creating a Facebook chat bot with api.ai (Dialogflow). The intents are working fine and I have done Facebook account linking by creating a Login button in messenger. The account linking is working and the account gets successfully linked. But I couldn't get the callback when the account is linked in Dialogflow.

There must be some Facebook account linking event that we can add in our intent to trigger the intent when the event is fired.

Please help how can we handle Facebook account linking with Dialogflow?

Comment: Can you post your errors and work so far?

Comment: As per docs you need a facebook account and a facebook page that you have to already know. What about the configuration of the [Callback URL](https://dialogflow.com/docs/integrations/facebook#webhook_configuration) ? In what step from the whole guide are stuck?

Comment: please post your so far work